# R: get columns that only have value 0

Tags: r, apply

sample code:

`df`:

```
#                        a                       b                       c
# 1 -0.0010616345688829504  -4.1135727372109387e-05 -0.0001814242939304348
```

There is only 1 row and 3000+ columns.

I was wondering how I can select only the columns with 0 (of which there is as I have confirmed looking at the data.)

Expecting something like this:

`res`:

```
#   d                        e                      f
# 1 0                        0                      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) all(x == 0), df)
#   d e f
#1 0 0 0
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   select_if(~ all(. == 0))
#  d e f
#1 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = -0.00106163456888295, b = -4.11357273721094e-05, 
    c = -0.000181424293930435, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one row, you could negate the columns (as `0 == FALSE`):

```
res <- df[, !df]
```

Or check for where `colSums` are `0`:

```
res <- df[, colSums(df) == 0]
```

Output:

```
  d e f
1 0 0 0
```

---

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(a = -0.00106163456888295, b = -4.11357273721094e-05, 
    c = -0.000181424293930435, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

---

A benchmark shows @akrun's `Filter` to be the fastest by far (haven't included the `dplyr` variant since it's by far the slowest):

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   which 25.1935 26.95415 29.42942 28.00300 31.34740 181.5487  1000
      == 14.2807 15.25200 16.84471 15.73310 16.92505 182.6126  1000
  Filter  1.6767  1.80705  2.02523  1.90270  1.99135   7.5026  1000
 colSums 11.0489 11.85425 12.83663 12.26115 13.04670  23.9469  1000
       ! 14.2278 15.07710 16.55270 15.55400 16.76835 187.0145  1000
```

[image]

Code for benchmark:

```
set.seed(3234)

ncols <- 3000
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rpois(ncols, 0.5), ncol = ncols))

bench <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(

  which = df[, which(df[1, ] == 0)],
  `==` = df[, df == 0],
  Filter = Filter(function(x) all(x == 0), df),
  colSums = df[, colSums(df) == 0],
  `!` = df[, !df],
  times = 1000

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Arguably the simplest solution is this (using @arg0naut91's data):

```
df[, df==0]
  d e f
1 0 0 0
```

Comment: returns `undefined columns selected` for me

Comment: Are you using @arg0naut91's `df`?

Answer (score 1):

```
df[,which(df[1,]==0)]
```

should do the job.